# Does adding new static member in middle break binary compatibility of a C++ library?

Tags: static-members, binary-compatibility

I have a class which has many static members, but I have added new function in the middle of the header file.

Does this break binary compatibility? Clients need to be recompiled?

**EDIT (1)**: Class has only static functions, no other functions and data members

Comment: It may, for example if you added a virtual method before a previously defined virtual method. Sounds like the answer _may_ be compiler dependent though, I'm aware of no guarantees when it comes to binary layout of classes when their definition is changed.

Comment: Class has only static functions, no other functions and data members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class has no *virtual functions*, so your new middle function will not change the *v-table*. Other static members in the class (functions and global variables/data) are invoked by the appropriate *symbol name* on Linux, Unix or Mac and your change is backward compatible.

But it's a breaking change on Windows because all functions are invoked by the *ordinal number* instead of the name (unless you are using *def* files to define custom ordinals for functions).

Try the [abi-cc](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool to automatically check backward  binary compatibility of your libraries.